# Break while loop inside for loop

Tags: php

How can I break while loop and for loop too when while loop is true?

```
<?php
for($i=0; $i<4; $i++){
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE weight='$i'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo $row['cell'];
        break; //I need to break the while loop and the for loop too in this line exactly, when he find and echo the "cell"!
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Wouldn't specifying `break 2;` work? 
See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Comment: Why do you need the outer loop then? Why don't you just hardcode `$i = 0;` ?

Comment: Read the Docs.. break accepts an optional numeric argument which tells it how many nested enclosing structures are to be broken out of.... its in here:: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is

```
break 2;
```

References:

- http://php.net/break

...

Answer (score 1):

Use Flags:

One flag inside while : Set this flag to 1 when you break while

One flag in outer for loop: If while loop flag is set then break for loop

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing a `break` why not do the following

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE weight BETWEEN 0 AND 3
```

OR just

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE weight = 0
```

You would be limiting querying the database multiple times and probably takes less time but you'd wouldn't notice it with a query like this.

Not sure why you there is a for loop then break on first iteration when you can just query the database and echo something. Unless OP has other plans for this code and reduced the code for SO the loop is really unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

use **exit** instead of **break**.

**break** results exit from current iteration while **exit** results exit from overall pgm.

Comment: So why would OP prefer `exit` over `break`?

Comment: in this case exit results exit from both while and for loop.

Comment: it does. But it stops the whole application, which is not the case. At least it's not obvious that it's what OP wants